# Unable to call function that is outside render, from inside render (in reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, render

My issue is from trying to call selectModal from inside the render function. I thought the problems was that I needed to bind the selectModal function in the constructor but that didn't help. I still get the same error of :

FolderIcon.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectModal' of undefined
    at singleClick (FolderIcon.js:37)

It works when i use the arrow function inside HTML tags like this, 
onClick={ () => this.selectModal('Modal A') },
but I am trying to open the popup only when an image is double clicked

Heres the code:

```
class FolderIcon extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modal: false,
            modalInfo: ""
          }
        this.selectModal = this.selectModal.bind(this);
    }

    selectModal = (info) => {
        this.setState({
            modal: !this.state.modal,
            modalInfo: info
        })
    }



    render() {

        let clicks = [];
        let timeout;

        function singleClick(event) {
            this.selectModal('Modal A');
            alert("single click");
        }

        function doubleClick(event) {
            alert('double clicked')
        }

        function clickHandler(event) {
            event.persist()
            event.preventDefault();
            clicks.push(new Date().getTime());
            window.clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
                if (clicks.length > 1 && clicks[clicks.length - 1] - clicks[clicks.length - 2] < 250) {
                    doubleClick(event.target);

                } else {
                    singleClick(event.target);
                }
            }, 250);
        }
        return (
            <>
            <div>
                <img src={foldericon} onClick={clickHandler} alt="" className="folder"/>

                <p onClick={ () => this.selectModal('Modal A') }>
                     Open Modal A
                </p>

                <Modal 
                displayModal={this.state.modal}
                modalInfo={this.state.modalInfo}
                closeModal={this.selectModal}/>
            </div>
            </>

        );
    }
}

export default FolderIcon;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you move your functions from render to the class itself. I don't see a reason here why they should be treated differently.

That way the `this` inside the singleClick function should reference the class defined, and the expected function should be found.

Comment: ty, I tried that before and i ran into some problems but I definitely will do what's suggested!

Answer (score 1):

value of `this` isn't what you expect inside `singleClick` function when it is called from inside the callback function of `setTimeout` function.

`this` should refer to your `FolderIcon` component for `singleClick` function to be able to call `selectModal` function

Change `singleClick` function to use arrow function syntax so that value `this` inside `singleClick` function is `FolderIcon` component

```
const singleClick = (event) => {
     this.selectModal('Modal A');
     alert("single click");
}
```

Comment: thanks! I see what you mean, I am gonna watch some videos on arrow functions to solidify the difference between regular functions and arrow functions